# Period of $x^n \mod y$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x$, $y$, $n$ be positive integers, where $n$ and $y$ shall be constants and $x$ a variable. Then it is trivial that the period of

$x \bmod y$

in $x$ is $y$, since the function simply drops to zero and starts over when $x$ reaches $y$. Now, for me at least, it is much less obvious, what the period of

$x^n \bmod y$

in $x$ should be. Visually (looking at plots of the function at different $n$ and $y$) the results suggest that the period still stays $y$. How can I see that analytically?

Comment: What does period mean?

Comment: If by period you mean order in a group then you're mistaken if you mean multiplication or addition. For instance, $2+2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ and $2 \times 2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, so $2$ has order $2$ in modulo-$4$ arithmetic under addition, and order $2$ in modulo-$3$ arithmetic under multiplication.

Comment: @William: the period $p$ is the smallest positive integer such that $(x+p)^n \equiv x^n\pmod y$.

Comment: The OP wants the period as a function in $x$, not as a function in $n$.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not a native speaker. I mean period just as $2\pi$ for $\sin(x)$.

Comment: @Fejwin: the keyword you want to look up is "modular arithmetic," in particular the fact that multiplication is compatible with taking remainders $\bmod y$.

Comment: You are looking for the order of $x^n$ in $\mathbb{Z}_y$.

Comment: I believe the functions in question are $f_1(x)=[x]_y$ and $f_2(x)=[x^n]_y$.  Clearly $f_1$ is periodic with period $y$, as $f_1(x+y)=[x+y]_y=[x]_y=f_1(x)$ for all $x$, and also if $f_1(x+z)=f_1(x)_y$ for all $x$, then $y$ divides $z$; thus $z=y$ is the smallest positive integer with this property.  It is also easily shown that $f_2(x+y)=[(x+y)^n]_y=[x^n]_y=f_2(x)$ for all $x$ (why?).  What is the smallest positive $z$ so that $f_2(x+z)=f_2(x)$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many cases where the period is $y$ (and, as Andre points out, many cases where it is not). If $y$ is squarefree (that is, if there is no integer $d\gt1$ such that $y$ is a multiple of $d^2$), then $x^n$ is zero if and only if $x$ is 0 (modulo $y$), so the period has to be $y$.

Answer (score 4):

The period need not be $y$. For example, let $y=9$, and consider the function $x^3$. This has period $3$. One can build many similar examples.